# Custom SwipeLayout change items in the runtime

Tags: android

I am using this SwipeLayout for my app:

[Accordion Swipe Layout](https://github.com/alexandrius/accordion-swipe-layout)

How to change the swipe items/colors during the runtime?

I tried changing them in the RecycleAdapter, but with no result. I don't get an error, but they simply won't change.

The adapter is mostly the one there, except I put my custom CardView in there.

Comment: You shoudl play around with styles, as it looks in the readme the creator left some attributes you can override in styles for your customitation https://github.com/alexandrius/accordion-swipe-layout#available-attrs / https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html?hl=es-419, you only have to inherit in the style from SwipeLayout and try override some of them to see how it change its appareance

Comment: well, as I said, I tried doing that in the RecyclerAdapter:

((SwipeLayout) itemView).setLeftItems(item.leftItems)

no success tho. It is not overrriding the main style.

Comment: check styles and theme link i left, thats very different from changing widget style from java code, read all correctly first..